# Keeping two wheeled wall following robot straight

Tags: two-wheeled

I have a two-wheeled (two DC motors) robot that needs to follow the wall beside the robot.

The issue is that the DC motors spin at different rates (because they are not identical, of course), so the robot does not go straight when the same voltage is provided to each motor.

How can I use IR distance sensors (and op-amps) to keep the distance from the wall constant?

(the robot must travel parallel to the wall)

Comment: [Duplicit](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/4967/keeping-two-wheeled-wall-following-robot-straight)

Comment: Can you provide some more information on your robot?  Specifically, can you use wheel encoders, can you use multiple distance sensors, is this going to be a purely analog robot, or will you have a processor, is the only thing it has to do is follow a wall? etc.

Comment: @Ben Good questions. 1) I cannot use wheel encoders, but I can use multiple distance sensors (however the less the better, of course). 2) Ideally, it is going to be a purely analog robot, however I can use ADCs and DACs (but no processor). 3) It has to be able to i) start with a flashlight shone on it (using photodiode or photoresistor), ii) follow the wall beside it, iii) turn around the wall at the end of it (the wall it is following will be a rectangular lab bench) and iv) stop within 1 meter from a surface placed in front of it.